# Django Incrementing Model Instance Attribute in Views w/ F()+1 and Accessing from Template

Tags: python, django, postgresql, model-view-controller, orm

So I have a model `Listing()` that has a field `views`. In my one of my views, when someone looks at the listing's page, the `views` field is incremented by one via `listing.views = F('views') + 1` and `listing.save(update_fields=['views'])`. My issue is that when I access the `views` attribute from that same template using `{{ listing.views }}`, instead of display the current amount of views, the template displays `F(views) + Value(1)` (literally that text). Now, I assume I could use a Model method such as `def get_views()` which will return `self.views`, but I was wondering why I am getting this weird issue. Also, is there a way without writing a model method that I can get the actual integer instead of the odd `F(views) + Value(1)`?

Here is my current code:

**models.py**

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    ...
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

**listings.py**

```
class ListingView(View):

def get(self, request):
    listing_id = request.GET['listing_id']
    listing = get_object_or_404(Listing, id=listing_id)

    listing.views = F('views') + 1
    listing.save(update_fields=['views'])

    return render(request, 'listings.html', {'listing': listing})
```

**listings.html**

```
<html>
    {{ listing.views }}
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure that this is appropriate use of `F objects`; any reason why you aren't using `listing.views += 1`?

Comment: Apparently it is more efficient from what I have read - but to be honest I am not 100% sure (although the code does work). If no one can provide a working alternative, I will default back to the code you suggested.

Comment: You're absolutely right! Huh. I've always used them to do in-query calculations. Anyhow, there's some documentation that may help you in the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using F expressions like this requires you to re-fetch the item once saved in order to get updated values (due to the nature of the F expression updating at a database level and not the model instance itself; perhaps that's where the decrease in operational costs come in).

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.F) -

*In order to access the new value that has been saved in this way, the object will need to be reloaded:*

```
reporter = Reporters.objects.get(pk=reporter.pk)
# Or, more succinctly:
reporter.refresh_from_db()
```

Comment: Thank you! One question though - since this refetches from the db, would it be a better optimization to just use `listing.views += 1` like you suggested instead?

Comment: Either way you'll deal w/ 2 DB hits, so I think they'd be essentially the same cost. Would be interested to hear anyone else's thoughts on this myself.